# Braintree Webhooks : transaction details via PHP

Tags: php, braintree

Braintree Payments supports Webhooks which return a subscription_id.  I have been looking for a PHP code sample that will return the transaction details for a given subscription_id.  The Braintree documentation provides no examples.

I know this code is wrong but I wanted to show some effort at a solution. :)

```
<?php
 $id = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
 require_once '_environment.php';
 $collection = Braintree_Transaction::search(array(
  Braintree_TransactionSearch::subscriptionId()->is($id)
 ));
 foreach ($collection AS $item) {
  echo "<li>" . $item->id;
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more help, you can always [reach out to our support team](http://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

You just need to [get the subscription](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/subscriptions/search):

```
$subscription = Braintree_Subscription::find('a_subscription_id');
```

It has a [list of all of its transactions](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/subscriptions/details#id15):

```
$transactions = $subscription->transactions;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't know PHP well enough to know how to use it.  Could you enhance it to show me how to echo the "customerDetails" (I think) "email"? Or point me to some code that uses your code?

Comment: I added this and I'm getting closer: foreach ($transaction AS $item) { echo($item); }

Comment: Nice that you guys actively monitor your tag here :) Is the support information [in the Braintree tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/braintree/info) still up to date?

Comment: This works: foreach ($transaction AS $item) { echo($item->customerDetails->email); }  Is this how you would do it?

Comment: @Inspired Yep, that's it.

Comment: @TimPost We try :). Thanks for the tip, looks like a bunch of the links in the tag wiki are  pointing to generic pages since our site redesign, though luckily the support and code example links are still good. We'll update it this week.